# Define searchFilter URL in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-filter

Currently I am working on a shop management project. The project is building with django, django-rest-framework and react. I want to filter the models data. So I have installed django-filter. I need to define the url like "http://localhost:8000/api/search-products/?category=oil&product=mustard oil". How can I do this?

My product search views is-

```
class SearchProduct(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["category", "name"]
```

My url is-

```
path("api/search-product/?<str:category>&<str:name>", SearchProduct.as_view())
```

Its showing page not found error.

How can I define the appropriate url path?

Comment: You don't have to define the query parameters in `urls.py`

Comment: Then how will it work?

Comment: Query params should not be part of the path url. They will still be covered though, and it will be handled by django-filter for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't define it as `path parameters`:

```
path("api/search-product/", SearchProduct.as_view())
```

and you can call endpoint like this:

```
.../api/search-product/?search=any_thing_you_want
```